# CasperJS passing data back to PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping, screen-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

CasperJS is being called by PHP using an `exec()` command. After CasperJS does its work such as retrieving parts of a webpage, how can the retrieved data be returned back to PHP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can redirect output from stdout to an array.

On [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) page it says you can do:

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

It goes on to say:

> If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command.

So basically you can do exec('casperjs command here, $array_here);

Answer (score 26):

I think the best way to transfer data from CasperJS to another language such as PHP is running CasperJS script as a service. Because CasperJS has been written over PhantomJS, CasperJS can use an embedded web server module of PhantomJS called Mongoose.

For information about how works the embedded web server see [here](http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/)

Here an example about how a CasperJS script can start a web server.

```
//define ip and port to web service
var ip_server = '127.0.0.1:8585';

//includes web server modules
var server = require('webserver').create();

//start web server
var service = server.listen(ip_server, function(request, response) {

    var links = [];
    var casper = require('casper').create();

    function getLinks() {
        var links = document.querySelectorAll('h3.r a');
        return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
            return e.getAttribute('href')
        });
    }

    casper.start('http://google.fr/', function() {
        // search for 'casperjs' from google form
        this.fill('form[action="/search"]', { q: 'casperjs' }, true);
    });

    casper.then(function() {
        // aggregate results for the 'casperjs' search
        links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
        // now search for 'phantomjs' by filling the form again
        this.fill('form[action="/search"]', { q: 'phantomjs' }, true);
    });

    casper.then(function() {
        // aggregate results for the 'phantomjs' search
        links = links.concat(this.evaluate(getLinks));
    });

    //
    casper.run(function() {
            response.statusCode = 200;
            //sends results as JSON object
            response.write(JSON.stringify(links, null, null));
            response.close();              
    });

});
console.log('Server running at http://' + ip_server+'/');
```

Comment: Whilst I agree that this is a good technique in theory, in practice casper does not free up phantomjs resources, there appears to be linearly increasing memory use with each request. I have tried adding ```casper.clear()``` and even hacking clear() to ```call this.page.close()``` (from within clear()) page. Whilst calling close appears to help it doesn't solve the problem.