# How to send data back to node from casperjs?

Tags: json, node.js, express, casperjs

How can I send data back to node, from a process launched via `execfile` in nodeJS? preferably in a JSON format.

This is how my code looks like right now:

```
//index.js NodeJS
var execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
var express = require('express');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var lchecker = execFile('/usr/local/bin/casperjs', [myprogram, myargs]);
    lchecker.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        var dataObject = JSON.parse(data); //This throws an error.
    }); 
});
```

The casperjs script that I'm calling returns JSON-like strings, like this:

```
console.log("[{href: targetLink.href, anchor: targetLink.anchor, isLive: 0, isFollowed: null}]");
```

**This is the error that I get**

When I'm trying to parse the JSON-like string, I get an error that says:

```
19 Jun 16:46:43 - [nodemon] starting node index.js
undefined:1
[{href: targetLink.href, anchor: targetLink.anchor, isLive: 1, isFollow: 1}]
  ^
Unexpected token h
```

So my JSON is invalid, and sincerely, I'm sure that there's a better way to send data back to node from casperjs, but I don't know how.

I've been thinking about creating a new route in express, and then make casperjs visit that route and pass the information via GET, and then manipulate that information in node. Is this a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though I received good and viable answers, I ultimately ended up outputting everything to stdout in casperjs, to send it back to PHP through a JSON array.

so in casperjs I wrote something like:

`console.log(JSON.stringify(targetLink))`

And then in node, I could just access that through `JSON.parse` and manipulate the data in any way I want.

EDIT:

I've run into this situation more often than not, so alternatively you can make CasperJS `POST` the information to a web endpoint, it's sometimes cleaner, but it adds overhead if you are worried about security and you need to make sure that only authorized scrapers can post data to your endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

I have used CasperJS on NodeJS by running CasperJs as a service.

Basically NodeJS through http.get() makes a request to CasperJS script which return a JSON object as response.

Here an example and more details about how a CasperJS script can start a web server:

[CasperJS passing data back to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852987/casperjs-passing-data-back-to-php/16489950#16489950)

Answer (score 1):

You may probably prefer to use something like SpookyJS (https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS) which offer the ability to use CasperJs inside a Node.js program.

I don't know if you will find the feature you want but it's probably cleaner anyway.