# best way to execute casperjs outside the command line

Tags: javascript, cmd, casperjs

I want to create an application (preferably web app) to provide an interface for casperjs from which tests can be run from without the use of the command line (I want the output of the tests to be displayed the same way it did on cmd). 
So the question is: Is there a way of excecuting commands from a web-app (so js) and also be able to get the output back? Do you think there are any problems that might arise using this approach? 
This is the only think I came up with. If you have any other suggestions on any ways that this can be achieved please let me know.

Comment: There are no problems as you didn't specify your server environment. Is it php, rails, java, node ...? Have you root access to it (can you install phantomjs and casperjs)?

Comment: this is going to run locally! I can do whatever I wish! I have already installed casperjs.

Comment: If you don't want to decide then this question is **too broad** or at least **primarily opinion-based**. Such a question is not a good fit for StackOverflow. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852987/casperjs-passing-data-back-to-php) for an example with php. If you want *continuous* console output to the web app, it will be much harder. If you want colorization of the output, you would need to do it yourself. You can also look into [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit)

Comment: I would like continuous output as you mentioned. I was hoping this would be possible with a simple html-js-php file.