# How can I expose my CasperJS tests as their own REST API?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs, headless-browser

I use simple uptime monitors like statuscake, uptimerobot, etc. to verify that my sites are up. The problem is that some of the sites are ASP.NET applications with complex `__doPostback` interactions -- basically, the user fills out a form, clicks submit, and then ASP.NET-generated javascript takes them to the next page.

My idea was to write a CasperJS (basically an easier API for PhantomJS) script to simulate this user interaction and test to make sure it works.

I have the test running in CasperJS and now I'd like to expose the test as its own REST API so I can have my uptime monitor hit it every few minutes. The REST API would return `200` if the test is successful; some error code if not.

I would normally throw restify or express around the logic, but you need to run CasperJS via `casperjs file.js` instead of via `node`, which means I can't run restify within it. I've looked at PhantomJS, Nightmare, and Zombie. If you know for sure those would work for this let me know; otherwise I had issues with their API that lead me back to CasperJS.

This feels a bit like exposing a test suite as an API if that gives any ideas.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

PhantomJS has a built-in server, you may use with CasperJS like shown in this answer: [CasperJS passing data back to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852987/casperjs-passing-data-back-to-php/16489950#16489950)

Comment: Thanks @Vaviloff, that seems to work but the comment below it suggests there is a memory leak, and I think I see why. `casper.run()` will `.exit()` by default afterwards (which kills the server). If you override its functionality by passing a callback function, you're supposed to call `.exit()` yourself, which the example does not. Because of this, casper stays running but the memory accumulates.