# Continues adding of tests to phantomjs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, phantomjs

I am new to PhantomJS, so this is maybe stupid.

I would like to create a testing environment, that will allow user to add tests (predefined) instantly and every test is run immediately.

Example (this tests are added dynamically):

- load page, compare load speed
- click on button, check if dialog opens
- close dialog, check if dialog is closed,...

Now in phantomjs I see this phantom.exit, and as I understand it, it closes phantomjs process. Is it possible to get the result and add new tests dynamically, without canceling phantomjs (phantom.exit)?

Comment: You could create a PhantomJS-based server with its own logic. See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852987/casperjs-passing-data-back-to-php/16489950#16489950

Comment: Is there maybe any documentation on creating my own server/Ionic?

Comment: Maybe you could adapt these answers to your task? [CasperJS server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852987/casperjs-passing-data-back-to-php/16489950#16489950), [Express.JS server to run Casper/Phantomjs scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34324672/how-to-control-a-casperjs-automation-script-from-a-remote-jquery-client-using-so/34328589#34328589)